# VBA script to insert INDEX/MATCH formula with dynamic reference/arrays

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I'm looking to simply insert an INDEX/MATCH formula in the column next to an existing selection (this will be part of a larger Sub). The reference/look-up array in the formula needs to be dynamic.

So far I've managed to successfully insert the formula. However, the reference/lookup-arrays have been manually input by me as I know the current Range (which is likely to change):

`Selection.Offset(0, 1) = "=INDEX($J$3:$J$31,MATCH(INDIRECT(""RC[-2]"",0),$H$3:$H$31,0))"`

How can I amend the `$J$3:$J$31` and the `$H$3:$H$31` to update dynamically? I've had success separately with something like 'Range("J3", Range("J3").End(xlDown))', but I can't seem to work it into the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can integrate variables into the formula, it becomes a bit tricky, and I imagine there are better ways to accomplish this, but it's the method I use when I need dynamic ranges in formulas in VBA. I'll provide an example below that should help:

I'm assuming the J3 and H3 will remain the same, but the end of the range is what you expect to change. If this is not the case, let me know.

You're essentially replacing the "31" in your range reference with " & [variable] & " (quotes included).

EDIT: I use Sheet1 as an example for the row count; so just update that to whatever the applicable sheet & range would be.

```
    Dim rCount As Long
    rCount = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Selection.Offset(0, 1) = "=INDEX($J$3:$J$" & rCount & ",MATCH(INDIRECT(""RC[-2]"",0),$H$3:$H$" & rCount & ",0))"
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! That pretty much works, but I had to amend `End(xlUp)` to `End(xlDown)` which seems to work. 

Two quick questions for my understanding if you or someone can help:                   
                                                                                                                                   
1: What does the 'A' mean in `Range("A" &` - I can't seem to figure that out.

2: The second line under `Dim` starting with `rCount` - I felt inclined to write 'Set' there, but it doesn't seem to work - is that not needed? Why?

Comment: The 'A' represents the first column of the worksheet. So if you use the same code, but change the "A" to a "J", then it will count the rows in column J instead. Just using a placeholder for the example :)


The 2nd bit: Set is used to assign an object reference, while just using "=" assigns the value to the variable, which in this case, would be the value of "number of rows".

Comment: Ah perfect. All makes sense! Many thanks for your help!